# gfortran make circular dependency dropped

Tags: makefile, fortran, mingw, gfortran

I'm running a makefile using GNU Make 4.1 on windows. I've seen a lot of SO links about this topic, but they all seem to be for C or c++. I'm not sure if the same rules apply, and since I'm using windows, syntax seems to be a bit different too.

Here's my make file:

```
 FC      = gfortran
 FCFLAGS = -O0 -Og -Wall -pedantic -fbacktrace -fcheck=all
 # FCFLAGS = -O2
 MODDIR = "bin"
 FCFLAGS += -J$(MODDIR) -fopenmp -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized

 SRCS_C =\
    gridFun.f90 \
    test.f90

 OBJS_C   = $(SRCS_C:.c=.o)
 TARGET = test

 all: $(TARGET)

 $(TARGET): $(OBJS_C)
    $(FC) -o $@ $(FCFLAGS)  $(OBJS_C)

 $(OBJS_C): $(SRCS_C)
    $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -c $(SRCS_C)

 cleanMod:
    del *.mod
 cleanObj:
    del *.o
```

I run my make file with

```
    gmake
```

and I've noticed that

```
    mingw32-make
```

seems to produce the same result. The error I'm getting is:

```
 gmake: Circular gridFun.f90 <- gridFun.f90 dependency dropped.
 gmake: Circular test.f90 <- gridFun.f90 dependency dropped.
 gmake: Circular test.f90 <- test.f90 dependency dropped.
 gfortran -O0 -Og -Wall -pedantic -fbacktrace -fcheck=all -J"bin" -fopenmp -fimpl
 icit-none -Wuninitialized -c gridFun.f90 test.f90
 gfortran -o test -O0 -Og -Wall -pedantic -fbacktrace -fcheck=all -J"bin" -fopenm
 p -fimplicit-none -Wuninitialized  gridFun.f90 test.f90
```

Any help about how to fix this, and maybe an explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have `c` sources so the `_C` suffix on variables is inaccurate (harmless but confusing).

The real issue is with this `OBJS_C   = $(SRCS_C:.c=.o)` [substitution ref](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs).

That's expecting to change `.c` files into `.o` files but you don't have any `.c` files.

Change that to `OBJS_C   = $(SRCS_C:.f90=.o)` and it should work for you.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. I'll accept your answer once I'm able to (10 minute minimum).